# Page number display issue with proc class

Tags: header-footer, page-numbering, two-column, document-classes, amsproc

I have just joined the community.

I have been learning LaTeX for a while from an online course and along the journey I encountered a problem. But the course instructor seemed unaware of it. I have given the code below, sorry its a bit lengthy. So there were no errors except that the page number at the bottom right corner of the single output page is not displayed properly.[image: The problem is circled red, top part of page cropped.] How to fix this? There is no problem in the article class. I used two graphic images placed side by side FYI.

```
\documentclass{proc}

\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{multirow}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{graphics/}}

\usepackage{caption, subcaption}

\title{More on Tables and Graphics}
\author{Some author}
\date{}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

Here we'll look at more table and graphics formatting.

\subsection{More on Tables}

Table~\ref{tab:wrapping} uses text wrapping in the last column.

\begin{table}[htbp]
\caption{Text Wrapping}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{| l | l | p{3cm} |}
\hline
CS101 & Java & Programming with Java\\
CS201 &  Languages & Programming Language Principles\\
CS301 & Compilers & Principles of compilers design and implementation\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\label{tab:wrapping}
\end{table}

Table~\ref{tab:multi} uses row and column span

\begin{table}[htbp]
\caption{Spanning rows and columns}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{| l | c | c |}
\hline
& \multicolumn{2}{c |}{Ranges} \\
\cline{2-3}
& X & Y \\
\hline
\multirow{3}{*}{Hot} & 7 & 9 \\
& 5 & 8 \\
& 6 & 7 \\
\hline
\multirow{3}{*}{Cold} & 4 & 9 \\
& 2 & 8 \\
& 3 & 5 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\label{tab:multi}
\end{table}

\subsection{More on graphics}

Both of my graphics are in the graphics folder for the subfigures, Figure~\ref{fig:paper} and Figure~\ref{fig:page} in Figure~\ref{fig:subs}.

\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.2\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=.5]{paper.png}
    \caption{Beginning}
    \label{fig:paper}
\end{subfigure}%
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.2\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=.5]{page.png}
    \caption{End}
    \label{fig:page}
\end{subfigure}%
\caption{The process}
\label{fig:subs}
\end{figure}

\section{Conclusion}

Now I know more about tables and graphics.

\end{document}
```

Comment: you are changing the margins and this clash with the settings in the class. If you want to use geometry you will have to reset footskip, e.g. `\usepackage[margin=1in,footskip=20pt]{geometry}`.

Comment: This modification solved the display problem! What is the purpose of footskip?

Comment: it is the distance between the text and the number in the footer.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because solved in comments.

Comment: @Dr. Manuel Kuehner Sorry for my delay in doing a more extended answer.

Comment: @SimonDispa Ah, yes. Your answer (+1) came after I voted to close, sorry :).

Comment: I voted to keep open, but I suggest to remove the intro of the question: future generations will not care about OP's course, but might very well be interested in OP's question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `layout` package helps to display margins and other page layout parameters.

There are differences between `\documentclass{proc}` and `\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}`, and also when including the `geometry` package.

The table is a summary of the main differences, showing in the first three columns what influences the vertical alignment.

[image: T]

(It is needed   `\usepackage[footskip=30pt,top=125.3pt, textheight=550pt, right =1in, left=1in ]{geometry}` to be close to the article + geometry layout)

**\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}**

[image: A]

**\documentclass[twocolumn]{article} plus geometry**

[image: AG]

**\documentclass{proc}**

[image: P]

**\documentclass{proc} plus geometry**

[image: PG]

All parameters of the current page can be accessed from within a LaTeX document without additional packages.

[image: PA]

```
% !TeX TS-program = pdflatex

\documentclass{proc}

\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}

\usepackage{layout} % show the layout of the page <<<<<<<<

\usepackage{multirow}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{graphics/}}

\usepackage{caption, subcaption}

\title{More on Tables and Graphics}
\author{Some author}
\date{}

\begin{document}
\layout  % show the layout of the page <<<<<<<<<<

\maketitle  

\section{Introduction}

Here we'll look at more table and graphics formatting.

\subsection{More on Tables}

Table~\ref{tab:wrapping} uses text wrapping in the last column.

\begin{table}[htbp]
    \caption{Text Wrapping}
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tabular}{| l | l | p{3cm} |}
            \hline
            CS101 & Java & Programming with Java\\
            CS201 &  Languages & Programming Language Principles\\
            CS301 & Compilers & Principles of compilers design and implementation\\
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
    \end{center}
    \label{tab:wrapping}
\end{table}

Table~\ref{tab:multi} uses row and column span

\begin{table}[htbp]
    \caption{Spanning rows and columns}
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tabular}{| l | c | c |}
            \hline
            & \multicolumn{2}{c |}{Ranges} \\
            \cline{2-3}
            & X & Y \\
            \hline
            \multirow{3}{*}{Hot} & 7 & 9 \\
            & 5 & 8 \\
            & 6 & 7 \\
            \hline
            \multirow{3}{*}{Cold} & 4 & 9 \\
            & 2 & 8 \\
            & 3 & 5 \\
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
    \end{center}
    \label{tab:multi}
\end{table}

\subsection{More on graphics}

Both of my graphics are in the graphics folder for the subfigures, Figure~\ref{fig:paper} and Figure~\ref{fig:page} in Figure~\ref{fig:subs}.

\begin{figure}[htbp]
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.2\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[scale=.2]{example-image}
        \caption{Beginning}
        \label{fig:paper}
    \end{subfigure}%
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.2\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[scale=.2]{example-image}
        \caption{End}
        \label{fig:page}
    \end{subfigure}%
    \caption{The process}
    \label{fig:subs}
\end{figure}

\section{Conclusion}

Now I know more about tables and graphics.

\vspace*{60pt}


footskip = \the\footskip

topmargin = \the\topmargin

textheight =\the\textheight

textwidth  = \the\textwidth

marginparwidth = \the\marginparwidth

columnsep = \the\columnsep
    
\end{document}
```